# How do I parse out a variable from my json string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing, json.net

I'm trying to parse the variable "name" from the following json string:

```
{"data":{"items":[{"name":"30-2169b (2/2)"}]},"account_id":12748781}
```

Why do I get an error when I use the following C# code?

```
string data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data").ToString();
```

I've tried:

```
string data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data").ToString();
string items= Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(data).SelectToken("items").ToString();
string name= Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(items).SelectToken("name").ToString();
```

but the first line throws an exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go down all the nodes in the json: data > items[index] (it's an array) > name.

```
string data = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["items"][0]["name"].ToString();
```

More examples here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm